# Detect when user leave my facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, offline

I am developing a Facebook WEB application and I want to know who is currently on line.

How can I detect when a user leave/close my application to change the user flag to offline.

Comment: There is no such state "logged into the app". As long as users logs into your application you need to track that manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by leave/close your application you mean navigate to a different webpage or close the browser?

The simplest way to achieve this, would be to periodically send a poll back to your webserver using an ajax connection and a javascript timer.

When a user disconnects from your app by closing the browser or changing webpage, the polling would stop happening.

A script running on your server would periodically check the timestamps of the polls of 'online' users, and if it finds one that's no longer up to date, mark the user as offline.

The wikipedia page on Comet (programming) is probably a good place to start

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: yes you are understand correctly. this sounds like something i should be afraid of concerning performance dose facebook can send my server a callback or something ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware Facebook doesn't send a callback to tell you that a user has left the page. You could also look into using onunload or onbeforeunload javascript events to trigger an ajax call to tell your server they are leaving.

Comment: thank you . "onbeforeunload" called every time i switch between pages..so i guess this is not a sure thing but i get the concept :)